# How can I determine the cause of a kernel panic?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel

I have a Tecno Spark 10 pro

I am trying to build a mainline Linux kernel straight from kernel.org. I have manually gone through `/sys/module` and generated a defconfig. How do I read the exact panic start from the ramoops. Here is the ramoops log. I dont know how to read the logs. Is there an article on step-by-step kernel debugging somewhere?

At the end it read `[   12.068722][    T1] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b ]---` Is it killing ramdisk img / is it a kernel init?

```
[    0.000000][    T0] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x411fd050]
[    0.000000][    T0] Linux version 6.3.1 (bret@lenovo) (aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 12.2.0-14ubuntu2) 12.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.40) #4 SMP Sat Jun 24 17:47:25 CAT 2023
[    0.000000][    T0] Machine model: MT6769H
[    0.000000][    T0] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000][    T0] [Firmware Bug]: Kernel image misaligned at boot, please fix your bootloader!
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: node ssmr-reserved-cma_memory compatible matching fail
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000023fff6000..0x000000023fffefff (36 KiB) nomap non-reusable ion-carveout-heap
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000008f000000..0x000000008fcfffff (13312 KiB) nomap non-reusable reserve-memory-scp_share
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x00000000bf000000..0x00000000bf3fffff (4096 KiB) nomap non-reusable consys-reserve-memory
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000009f3f0000..0x000000009f8fffff (5184 KiB) nomap non-reusable reserve-memory-sspm_share
[    0.000000][    T0] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x00000000be000000, size 3 MiB
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: initialized node wifi-reserve-memory, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x00000000be000000..0x00000000be2fffff (3072 KiB) nomap non-reusable wifi-reserve-memory
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000004ce00000..0x000000004ce5ffff (384 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-6-atf-reserved
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000004d000000..0x000000004d00ffff (64 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-12-aee_debug_kinfo
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000004d010000..0x000000004d0effff (896 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-13-pstore
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000004d0f0000..0x000000004d0fffff (64 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-14-minirdump
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000006e000000..0x000000006f61ffff (22656 KiB) map non-reusable mblock-22-ap_md_c_smem
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x0000000070000000..0x000000007106ffff (16832 KiB) map non-reusable mblock-21-ap_md_nc_smem
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x00000000755e0000..0x00000000755effff (64 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-17-SPM-reserved
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x0000000077030000..0x00000000793fffff (36672 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-16-framebuffer
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x0000000079400000..0x000000007f3fffff (98304 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-11-tee-reserved
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000007f400000..0x000000007f5fffff (2048 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-9-tee-secmem
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000007f600000..0x000000007f640fff (260 KiB) map non-reusable mblock-4-gz-log
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000007f6f8000..0x000000007f6fffff (32 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-15-tkv
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000007f700000..0x000000007f7bffff (768 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-10-SSPM-reserved
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000007f7c0000..0x000000007f7fffff (256 KiB) map non-reusable mblock-5-log_store
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000007f800000..0x000000007fffffff (8192 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-3-gz
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000009f900000..0x000000009fefffff (6144 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-18-SCP-reserved
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000009fff0000..0x000000009fffffff (64 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-19-ccci_tag_mem
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x00000000a2000000..0x00000000b1ffffff (262144 KiB) map non-reusable mblock-20-md_mem_usage
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x00000000bff40000..0x00000000bff7ffff (256 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-8-atf-log-reserved
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x00000000bff80000..0x00000000bfffffff (512 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-7-atf-ramdump-reserved
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000013ffff000..0x000000013fffffff (4 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-1-dramc-rk0
[    0.000000][    T0] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000023ffff000..0x000000023fffffff (4 KiB) nomap non-reusable mblock-2-dramc-rk1
[    0.000000][    T0] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000][    T0]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   DMA32    empty
[    0.000000][    T0]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000023fffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000][    T0] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x000000004cdfffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000004ce00000-0x000000004ce5ffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000004ce60000-0x000000004cffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000004d000000-0x000000004d0fffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000004d100000-0x00000000755dffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000755e0000-0x00000000755effff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000755f0000-0x000000007702ffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000077030000-0x000000007f5fffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000007f600000-0x000000007f6f7fff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000007f6f8000-0x000000007f7bffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000007f7c0000-0x000000007f7fffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000007f800000-0x000000007fffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x000000008effffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000008f000000-0x000000008fcfffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000008fd00000-0x000000009f3effff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000009f3f0000-0x000000009fefffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000009ff00000-0x000000009ffeffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000009fff0000-0x000000009fffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000a0000000-0x00000000bdffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000be000000-0x00000000be2fffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000be300000-0x00000000beffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bf000000-0x00000000bf3fffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bf400000-0x00000000bff3ffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bff40000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x000000013fffefff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000013ffff000-0x000000013fffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000140000000-0x000000023fff5fff]
[    0.000000][    T0]   node   0: [mem 0x000000023fff6000-0x000000023fffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x000000023fffffff]
[    0.000000][    T0] psci: probing for conduit method from DT.
[    0.000000][    T0] psci: PSCIv1.1 detected in firmware.
[    0.000000][    T0] psci: Using standard PSCI v0.2 function IDs
[    0.000000][    T0] psci: MIGRATE_INFO_TYPE not supported.
[    0.000000][    T0] psci: SMC Calling Convention v1.1
[    0.000000][    T0] No bootconfig data provided, so skipping bootconfig
[    0.000000][    T0] percpu: Embedded 25 pages/cpu s65064 r8192 d29144 u102400
[    0.000000][    T0] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000][    T0] CPU features: detected: GIC system register CPU interface
[    0.000000][    T0] CPU features: detected: Qualcomm erratum 1009, or ARM erratum 1286807, 2441009
[    0.000000][    T0] CPU features: detected: ARM errata 1165522, 1319367, or 1530923
[    0.000000][    T0] alternatives: applying boot alternatives
[    0.000000][    T0] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 2068480
[    0.000000][    T0] Kernel command line: console=tty0 console=ttyS0,921600n1 root=/dev/ram vmalloc=400M slub_debug=OFZPU swiotlb=noforce cgroup.memory=nosocket,nokmem firmware_class.path=/vendor/firmware page_owner=on loop.max_part=7 has_battery_removed=0 FlashID=Hosing+4D4D43313238 loop.max_part=7 androidboot.boot_devices=bootdevice,soc/11230000.mmc,11230000.mmc,soc/11230000.msdc,11230000.msdc ramoops.mem_address=0x4d010000 ramoops.mem_size=0xe0000 ramoops.pmsg_size=0x10000 ramoops.console_size=0x40000 androidboot.blow_disbrom=0 bootopt=64S3,32N2,64N2 androidboot.selinux=permissive console=ttyGS0,115200 PN=CY-KI7-V7510 root=/dev/ram  androidboot.slot_suffix=_a androidboot.slot=a androidboot.verifiedbootstate=orange androidboot.efusemode=hw androidboot.efuse=1 androidboot.atm=disabled sfi=0x00000000 vcore_num=0 androidboot.force_normal_boot=1 androidboot.meta_log_disable=0 androidboot.hwrev=PVT androidboot.hwmodel=KI7 androidboot.boardid=BOM1 androidboot.adctest=150_150_150 androidboot.secureboot=[secboot:(1)sec_usbdl:(1)efus
[    0.000000][    T0] Unknown kernel command line parameters "vmalloc=400M slub_debug=OFZPU page_owner=on has_battery_removed=0 FlashID=Hosing+4D4D43313238 bootopt=64S3,32N2,64N2 PN=CY-KI7-V7510 sfi=0x00000000 vcore_num=0 tran_cpu_model=mt6769 mem_index=6 emmc_cid=HOSING_4d4d43313238 tkv=2138013696 usb2jtag_mode=0", will be passed to user space.
[    0.000000][    T0] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000][    T0] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000][    T0] mem auto-init: stack:all(zero), heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000][    T0] Memory: 7715228K/8388608K available (14208K kernel code, 2290K rwdata, 8216K rodata, 5632K init, 411K bss, 673380K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000][    T0] ftrace: allocating 42600 entries in 167 pages
[    0.000000][    T0] ftrace: allocated 167 pages with 5 groups
[    0.000000][    T0] 
[    0.000000][    T0] **********************************************************
[    0.000000][    T0] **   NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE   **
[    0.000000][    T0] **                                                      **
[    0.000000][    T0] ** trace_printk() being used. Allocating extra memory.  **
[    0.000000][    T0] **                                                      **
[    0.000000][    T0] ** This means that this is a DEBUG kernel and it is     **
[    0.000000][    T0] ** unsafe for production use.                           **
[    0.000000][    T0] **                                                      **
[    0.000000][    T0] ** If you see this message and you are not debugging    **
[    0.000000][    T0] ** the kernel, report this immediately to your vendor!  **
[    0.000000][    T0] **                                                      **
[    0.000000][    T0] **   NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE   **
[    0.000000][    T0] **********************************************************
[    0.000000][    T0] trace event string verifier disabled
[    0.000000][    T0] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000][    T0] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000][    T0] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=8.
[    0.000000][    T0]  Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000][    T0] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000][    T0] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=8
[    0.000000][    T0] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000][    T0] GICv3: 480 SPIs implemented
[    0.000000][    T0] GICv3: 0 Extended SPIs implemented
[    0.000000][    T0] Root IRQ handler: gic_handle_irq
[    0.000000][    T0] GICv3: GICv3 features: 16 PPIs
[    0.000000][    T0] GICv3: CPU0: found redistributor 0 region 0:0x000000000c040000
[    0.000000][    T0] rcu: srcu_init: Setting srcu_struct sizes based on contention.
[    0.000000][    T0] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 13.00MHz (virt).
[    0.000000][    T0] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2ff89eacb, max_idle_ns: 440795202429 ns
[    0.000000][    T0] sched_clock: 56 bits at 13MHz, resolution 76ns, wraps every 4398046511101ns
[    0.001200][    T0] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.001214][    T0] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    0.002281][    T0] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 26.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=52000)
[    0.002309][    T0] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.002615][    T0] Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.002657][    T0] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.005097][    T1] cblist_init_generic: Setting adjustable number of callback queues.
[    0.005125][    T1] cblist_init_generic: Setting shift to 3 and lim to 1.
[    0.005383][    T1] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.005402][    T1] rcu:     Max phase no-delay instances is 1000.
[    0.006560][    T1] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.007083][    T1] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.009138][    T0] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU1
[    0.009198][    T0] GICv3: CPU1: found redistributor 100 region 0:0x000000000c060000
[    0.009235][    T0] CPU1: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000100 [0x411fd050]
[    0.011263][    T0] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU2
[    0.011308][    T0] GICv3: CPU2: found redistributor 200 region 0:0x000000000c080000
[    0.011333][    T0] CPU2: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000200 [0x411fd050]
[    0.013399][    T0] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU3
[    0.013440][    T0] GICv3: CPU3: found redistributor 300 region 0:0x000000000c0a0000
[    0.013463][    T0] CPU3: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000300 [0x411fd050]
[    0.015440][    T0] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU4
[    0.015481][    T0] GICv3: CPU4: found redistributor 400 region 0:0x000000000c0c0000
[    0.015502][    T0] CPU4: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000400 [0x411fd050]
[    0.017494][    T0] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU5
[    0.017537][    T0] GICv3: CPU5: found redistributor 500 region 0:0x000000000c0e0000
[    0.017559][    T0] CPU5: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000500 [0x411fd050]
[    0.019611][    T0] CPU features: detected: Spectre-BHB
[    0.019619][    T0] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU6
[    0.019652][    T0] GICv3: CPU6: found redistributor 600 region 0:0x000000000c100000
[    0.019669][    T0] CPU6: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000600 [0x413fd0a1]
[    0.021626][    T0] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU7
[    0.021666][    T0] GICv3: CPU7: found redistributor 700 region 0:0x000000000c120000
[    0.021684][    T0] CPU7: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000700 [0x413fd0a1]
[    0.021764][    T1] smp: Brought up 1 node, 8 CPUs
[    0.021964][    T1] SMP: Total of 8 processors activated.
[    0.021979][    T1] CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL0 Support
[    0.021993][    T1] CPU features: detected: Data cache clean to the PoU not required for I/D coherence
[    0.022009][    T1] CPU features: detected: Common not Private translations
[    0.022023][    T1] CPU features: detected: CRC32 instructions
[    0.022037][    T1] CPU features: detected: RCpc load-acquire (LDAPR)
[    0.022050][    T1] CPU features: detected: LSE atomic instructions
[    0.022063][    T1] CPU features: detected: Privileged Access Never
[    0.022076][    T1] CPU features: detected: RAS Extension Support
[    0.022195][    T1] CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL1
[    0.022212][    T1] alternatives: applying system-wide alternatives
[    0.065581][    T1] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.065608][    T1] futex hash table entries: 2048 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.065716][    T1] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.066363][    T1] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.066659][    T1] NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
[    0.067419][    T1] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
[    0.067553][    T1] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations
[    0.067679][    T1] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
[    0.067767][    T1] ramoops: using module parameters
[    0.069646][    T1] printk: console [ramoops-1] enabled
[    0.070789][    T1] pstore: Registered ramoops as persistent store backend
[    0.070806][    T1] ramoops: using 0xe0000@0x4d010000, ecc: 0
[    0.071570][    T1] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.071861][    T1] ASID allocator initialised with 65536 entries
[    0.076570][    T1] OF: /scp_dvfs: could not get #gpio-cells for /gpio@10005000
[    0.095206][    T1] platform gce_mbox_bdg: Fixed dependency cycle(s) with /gce_mbox_bdg
[    0.109072][    T1] OF: /spi0@1100a000/fingerprint@0: could not get #gpio-cells for /cpus/idle-states/idlebus26m
[    0.109106][    T1] OF: /spi0@1100a000/fingerprint@0: could not get #gpio-cells for /topckgen@10000000
[    0.119455][    T1] platform 14000000.mmsys_config: Fixed dependency cycle(s) with /mmsys_config@14000000
[    0.143938][    T1] iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
[    0.143962][    T1] iommu: DMA domain TLB invalidation policy: strict mode 
[    0.144381][    T1] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.144661][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.144709][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.144768][    T1] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.145144][    T1] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.145223][    T1] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.147627][    T1] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.148175][    T1] nfc: nfc_init: NFC Core ver 0.1
[    0.148247][    T1] NET: Registered PF_NFC protocol family
[    0.292497][    T1] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.292773][    T1] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.292813][    T1] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.297425][    T1] NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family
[    0.297675][    T1] IP idents hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.302360][    T1] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.302433][    T1] Table-perturb hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.302456][    T1] TCP established hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.302728][    T1] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes, linear)
[    0.303836][    T1] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 65536 bind 65536)
[    0.303940][    T1] UDP hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.304079][    T1] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.304897][    T1] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.304919][    T1] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.304933][    T1] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.304944][    T1] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.305953][   T54] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.339971][    T1] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    0.340163][    T1] workingset: timestamp_bits=62 max_order=21 bucket_order=0
[    0.341819][    T1] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/W].
[    0.341857][    T1] ntfs3: Max link count 4000
[    0.341870][    T1] ntfs3: Enabled Linux POSIX ACLs support
[    0.341882][    T1] ntfs3: Warning: Activated 64 bits per cluster. Windows does not support this
[    0.341895][    T1] ntfs3: Read-only LZX/Xpress compression included
[    0.341915][    T1] romfs: ROMFS MTD (C) 2007 Red Hat, Inc.
[    0.341935][    T1] fuse: init (API version 7.38)
[    0.367538][    T1] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.367562][    T1] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.367638][    T1] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 247)
[    0.367654][    T1] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    0.367667][    T1] io scheduler kyber registered
[    0.367697][    T1] io scheduler bfq registered
[    0.758889][   T54] Freeing initrd memory: 15444K
[   10.943974][    T1] brd: module loaded
[   10.949131][    T1] loop: module loaded
[   10.951017][    T1] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[   10.951137][    T1] PPP MPPE Compression module registered
[   10.951153][    T1] NET: Registered PF_PPPOX protocol family
[   10.951205][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
[   10.951254][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver ax88179_178a
[   10.951307][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   10.951353][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver net1080
[   10.951400][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_subset
[   10.951448][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver zaurus
[   10.951502][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[   10.951547][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8153_ecm
[   10.951595][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   10.952053][    T1] UDC core: g_serial: couldn't find an available UDC
[   10.953437][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver xpad
[   10.954916][    T1] mtk-wdt 10007000.toprgu: Watchdog enabled (timeout=31 sec, nowayout=0)
[   10.955947][    T1] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.47.0-ioctl (2022-07-28) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[   10.962712][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   10.962732][    T1] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   10.965862][    T1] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   10.967087][    T1] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 0000000000000008
[   10.967106][    T1] Mem abort info:
[   10.967117][    T1]   ESR = 0x0000000096000005
[   10.967128][    T1]   EC = 0x25: DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[   10.967142][    T1]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[   10.967155][    T1]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[   10.967165][    T1]   FSC = 0x05: level 1 translation fault
[   10.967178][    T1] Data abort info:
[   10.967188][    T1]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000005
[   10.967199][    T1]   CM = 0, WnR = 0
[   10.967209][    T1] [0000000000000008] user address but active_mm is swapper
[   10.967223][    T1] Internal error: Oops: 0000000096000005 [#1] SMP
[   10.967236][    T1] Modules linked in:
[   10.967249][    T1] CPU: 7 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.3.1 #4
[   10.967264][    T1] Hardware name: MT6769H (DT)
[   10.967273][    T1] pstate: 60400005 (nZCv daif +PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[   10.967287][    T1] pc : mt6358_platform_driver_probe+0x4c/0x108
[   10.967310][    T1] lr : mt6358_platform_driver_probe+0x3c/0x108
[   10.967324][    T1] sp : ffffffc00808bb80
[   10.967334][    T1] x29: ffffffc00808bb80 x28: ffffffc009736968 x27: ffffffc009680130
[   10.967353][    T1] x26: ffffffc009607348 x25: ffffffc00966f5a8 x24: ffffff80c5ccc868
[   10.967371][    T1] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: 0000000000000000 x21: ffffff80c1939000
[   10.967389][    T1] x20: ffffff80c1939010 x19: ffffff80c5ccc780 x18: ffffffffffffffff
[   10.967406][    T1] x17: 6c616e7265746e69 x16: 5f6464615f746365 x15: ffffffc00808b870
[   10.967424][    T1] x14: ffffff80c5ccda0a x13: ffffff80c5ccda08 x12: 27203a746573202c
[   10.967441][    T1] x11: 2773726576697264 x10: 0000000000061ec0 x9 : ffffffc00876cefc
[   10.967458][    T1] x8 : ffffff80c5ccc800 x7 : ffffffc009df3ec0 x6 : 000000000000003f
[   10.967476][    T1] x5 : 0000000000000000 x4 : ffffffc008088000 x3 : 0000000000000000
[   10.967493][    T1] x2 : 0000000000000000 x1 : ffffffc008a3d45c x0 : ffffff80c5ccc780
[   10.967510][    T1] Call trace:
[   10.967519][    T1]  mt6358_platform_driver_probe+0x4c/0x108
[   10.967533][    T1]  platform_probe+0x70/0xd0
[   10.967550][    T1]  really_probe+0x168/0x3e8
[   10.967563][    T1]  __driver_probe_device+0x90/0x180
[   10.967576][    T1]  driver_probe_device+0x44/0x120
[   10.967590][    T1]  __driver_attach+0x134/0x1f8
[   10.967602][    T1]  bus_for_each_dev+0x80/0xe8
[   10.967615][    T1]  driver_attach+0x2c/0x40
[   10.967627][    T1]  bus_add_driver+0x100/0x228
[   10.967639][    T1]  driver_register+0x68/0x138
[   10.967652][    T1]  __platform_driver_register+0x30/0x48
[   10.967666][    T1]  mt6358_platform_driver_init+0x24/0x38
[   10.967680][    T1]  do_one_initcall+0x78/0x248
[   10.967693][    T1]  kernel_init_freeable+0x18c/0x330
[   10.967708][    T1]  kernel_init+0x30/0x1f8
[   10.967720][    T1]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
[   10.967736][    T1] Code: b40005e0 f9000014 aa0003f3 f9003e80 (f94006c1) 
[   10.967748][    T1] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[   10.979577][    T1] pstore: backend (ramoops) writing error (-28)
[   10.979604][    T1] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b
[   10.979618][    T1] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[   12.056646][    T1] SMP: failed to stop secondary CPUs 2-7
[   12.056659][    T1] Kernel Offset: disabled
[   12.056668][    T1] CPU features: 0x600000,00200406,3200720b
[   12.056679][    T1] Memory Limit: none
[   12.068722][    T1] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b ]---
```

Comment: My guesses are that problem is in user space. Your init process seems not working (either it cannot load needed libraries, or some other problems). Try to use a static linked bash and use that as init. In such case you find quickly if the problem is there or really in kernel.

Comment: I doubt if it reached init in ramdisk.. I still think it's panicking before it starts executing init if I use a prebuilt kernel with the same ramdisk, it doesn't panic

Comment: Maybe, but the error AFAIK it is when executing init (so maybe init is not found on the expected location.

Comment: Alright noted, I will change try using a simple script and see what gives